# XLWorkbook only saving first row of data from an SQL Query

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to use C# to get data from MySql database and export that data into Excel. For some reason, I am only getting the first row of data. I am not sure what is wrong. Below is my code:

```
public void MySqlConnectionHandler(string SQL_QUERY)
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectionString = " SERVER = some_ip_address;"
                               + "DATABASE = database ;"
                               + "UID=user;"
                               + "PASSWORD=password";
            connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(SQL_QUERY,connection);
            DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dbdataset);
            XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dbdataset, "myworktable");
            wb.SaveAs("myworktable.xlsx");
            MessageBox.Show("Connected");

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "MySQL Query Failure");

        }
    }

 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AggAutomation agg = new AggAutomation();
        agg.MySqlConnectionHandler("SELECT * FROM data_base;");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. It was a silly mistake. The datatable that I was reading in actually only had one data point